Create a list accumulating the results of calling a function repeatedly on an input value
Is there a library function that creates recursive lists in the following sense,
recursive_list(f, x0, n) = [x0, f(x0), f(f(x0)), f(f(f(x0))), ...]

with n elements in the returned list?
If not, how can this be written?

You could use itertools.accumulate, which works like reduce but gives you every intermediate value
def repeated_application(f_unary, x0, n):
    def f_binary(acc, _):
        return f_unary(acc)
    return itertools.accumulate(range(n), f_binary, initial=x0)

You just have to turn the unary function into a binary one.
Note, this returns an iterator (more general that way).
Also, the way n is supposed to work is underspecified, you can twiddle with it to fit your requirements
I also want to point out, the straightforward way using basic language constructs is perfectly acceptable;
def recursive_application(f, x0, n):
    acc = x0
    result = [acc]
    for _ in range(n):
        acc = f(acc)
        result.append(acc)
    return result

Or as a generator, it's very clean:
def repeated_application(f, x0, n):
    acc = x0
    yield acc
    for _ in range(n):
        acc = f(acc)
        yield acc


Not in Python's standard library, but more-itertools (recommended by Python's itertools documentation) has iterate and take:
from more_itertools import iterate, take

f, x0, n = lambda x: 2*x, 1, 10

print(take(n, iterate(f, x0)))

Output:
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512]


There is no such function in the standard library, but it wouldn't take much code to write one:
def recursive_list(f, x, n):
    return [x] + [x := f(x) for i in range(n-1)]


Nice. Why :=? Won't = do?

@EvanAad because = would be a syntax error, that is part of an assignment statement, you need an assignment expression which uses :=

This code does an unnecessary list addition (involving an unnecessary copy of an O(n) list).

@pts this is true, but in my experience writing Python professionally this is almost never a salient issue, copying one buffer to another is one of the fastest things you can do, and in terms of memory, it's rarely a problem.

As suggested here use repeat and reduce:
from itertools import repeat
from functools import reduce
def repeated(func, n):
    def apply(x, f):
        return f(x)
    def ret(x):
        return reduce(apply, repeat(func, n), x)
    return ret

recursive_list = [repeated(f, i) for i in range(5)]

The elements in the recursive list are functions.
For example:
def f(x):
    return x*x
recursive_list[3](2)
# 256


sooo this repeates f i number of times from i=0 -> n, which scales quadratically, but you only need to apply f n times (linearly) (I didn't downvote, btw)

@juanpa.arrivillaga Granted, f is only called "on demand", not when the list is constructed. This makes creating the list rather pointless, though, repeated could just be used directly.

@mkrieger1 yes, the list is pointless but the question requested a list

Yes, a list of values, not a list of functions.

@mkrieger1 right, thanks for pointing out, I had overseen the fact that the list should contain values and not functions
